# CSS Matrix animation issue

Tags: css, matrix

I've tried to create some matrices animation lately. But I noticed something weird. The following code works differently on Firefox, Safari and Chrome :

```
@-moz-keyframes matrix
{
    from 
    { 
       -moz-transform: matrix(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    }

    to 
    { 
       -moz-transform: matrix(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0.0, 12.0);
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes matrix
{
    from 
    { 
        -webkit-transform: matrix(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    }

    to 
    { 
        -webkit-transform: matrix(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 1.0, 0.0, 12.0);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to fix this problem ?

Comment: 1+ I can confirm this. http://jsfiddle.net/ACtkY/1/

Comment: What's interesting is that if you dont use the keyframes, and just apply the transform, the result is the same across different browsers, yet the webkit animation animates to something different.. and then flickers to the right thing for a moment as the animation ends. Looks more like a bug than a difference in rendering, since it's not animating to the proper state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be just a difference in the way Gecko and Webkit renders the `matrix` function, which is why they still have the experimental vendor prefixes. I say there is no clean cut way of "fixing" this issue, as it is entirely up to the rendering engine, so you may just have to tinker with the values to get equivalent results.